# Access method from class in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

I have my model.js like this :

```
export class Piece {
constructor(name, coordinate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.coordinate = coordinate;
    this.move = false;
  }
  init(){
    // some stuff
  }
  hasOne(){
    // some stuff
  }
}

export class Brick {
  constructor(name, level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
  }
  getScore(level){
    // some stuff
  }
}

export class Dashboard {
  constructor(){
    this.start();
  }

  start(){
    this.firstPiece = new Piece('A', 5);
  }

}
```

...

and i have my component Dashboard

```
import * as Model from './model';
<Dashboard game={new Model.Dashboard()} />
```

And Piece

```
import React from 'react';
const Piece = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return(
    <div>
      {props.piece.init()}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Piece;
```

When i console.log(props), i only see the constructor props, i have no access to methods init(), only with **proto**

```
{props.piece.__proto__.init()}
```

Is there a way to access method in props without passing by **proto** ?

Comment: Is `props.piece` the class itself or just an instance of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses [prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482), and ES6 classes are syntactic sugar for established inheritance recipe.

The understanding of prototypal inheritance is essential for effective JavaScript development.

`piece` prototypically inherits `init` from `Piece` class, `piece.__proto__ === Piece.prototype`. `__proto__` is non-standard property that is used internally and shouldn't be used directly.

Due to how inheritance works, `piece.init === piece.__proto__.init`, unless it was shadowed. The method is expected to be used like `{props.piece.init()}` without problems.